# configureView lblNome (null)

Tags: ios

I would like to bring the label telaDetalhe.PropriedadenNomeAnimal.text = @ "leao", for configureView within the method, but the value is null.

ViewController.m

```
//IMPORTE o ".h" DA TELA DE DETALHE  E CARREGUE OS DADOS PELA SEGUE

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    //Quando ocorrer acao da segue, verifica se foi a que exibe o detalhe
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"leao"]) {

        //Instancia a tela de detalhe
        DetalheViewController *telaDetalhe = segue.destinationViewController;
        //Atribui o item selecionado a propriedade da tela
        telaDetalhe.PropriedadenNomeAnimal.text = @"leao";

    }
}
```

DetalheViewController.h

```
@interface DetalheViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *lblNome;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *PropriedadenNomeAnimal;
```

DetalheViewController.m

```
// default initWith...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //chamo o metodo
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)configureView
{
    lblNome.text = self.PropriedadenNomeAnimal.text;
}

// default memory warning
```

Comment: It will be easier for people to understand your code and your comments if you stick with English.

Comment: Are you sure it is connected?